# Cannot send two arguments from a WebClient

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, shields, web-service

I am using the Arduino WifiWebClient to insert records into a RoR (Ruby on Rails) app. It works but it only inserts one field regardless of the number of arguments I send.

For example, if I test with Curl

```
curl -d "sale[itemId]=1234&sale[machineId]=4567"  http://myapp.herokuapp.com/sales
```

It will create a Sale record and populate both fields itemId and machineId. Everything OK.

But when I send the following instruction from the Arduino, it will only populate the first field:

(I am only including the POST method to simplifly the code, the rest of the code is similar to http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiClient)

```
void sendPOST() //client function to send/receive POST request data.
{
if (client.connect(URL,PORT)) {  //starts client connection, checks for connection
Serial.println("connected");

Serial.println("POST /sales HTTP/1.1"); //download text
Serial.println("From: Arduino1");
Serial.println("Host: evening-sierra-3769.herokuapp.com");
Serial.println("User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.1");
Serial.println("Connection: close");
Serial.println("Cache-Control : no-cache");
Serial.println("Pragma: no-cache");
Serial.println("Expires: -1");
Serial.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Serial.print("Content-Length: ");
Serial.println(31);
Serial.println();
Serial.println("sale[machineId]=\"09876543211234\"");
Serial.println("sale[itemId]=\"09876543211234\"");
Serial.println();

client.println("POST /sales HTTP/1.1"); //download text
client.println("From: Arduino1");
client.println("Host: evening-sierra-3769.herokuapp.com");  // Will be needed if apache is configured for VHOSTS
client.println("User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.1");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println("Cache-Control : no-cache");
client.println("Pragma: no-cache");
client.println("Expires: -1");
client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.println(31);
client.println();
client.println("sale[machineId]=09876543211234\r\n");
client.println("sale[itemId]=09876543211234\r\n");
client.println();

Serial.println("ARDUINO: HTTP message sent");
delay(3000);
if(client.available())
{
  Serial.println("ARDUINO: HTTP message received");
  Serial.println("ARDUINO: printing received headers and script response...\n");

  while(client.available())
  {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
}
else
{
  Serial.println("ARDUINO: no response received / no response received in time");
}

client.stop();
}
```

Comment: `31` is not the right content-length for the whole content you try to post. It only includes the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Changed the following lines:

```
client.println("Content-Type: multipart/form-data");   
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.println(63);
client.println();
client.println("sale[itemId]=123456789012341234&sale[machineId]=123456789012341234\r\n");
client.println();
```